# Execution of Oracle Ad Hoc query with Bind Parameters Erroring Out; ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to execute an ad hoc query with a parameter (bind variable) using Visual Studio 2010 (.NET 4.0) and ODP 4.112.3.0, Oracle11g.  It's operating in a 32 bit application pool under ASP.NET.  I have the following code:

```
Public Shared Function LookupUpc(ByVal upc As Long) As DataTable
    Dim upcLookup As New DataTable
    Dim sql As String = "OPEN :outCursor FOR SELECT * FROM IMPROD.UPC_ID_XREF " + _
                        "INNER JOIN IMPROD.UPC_ID_DESCRIPTIONS ON IMPROD.UPC_ID_XREF.UPC_ID = IMPROD.UPC_ID_DESCRIPTIONS.UPC_ID " + _
                        "INNER JOIN IMPROD.UPC_ID_ATTRIBUTES ON IMPROD.UPC_ID_XREF.UPC_ID = IMPROD.UPC_ID_ATTRIBUTES.UPC_ID " + _
                        "WHERE IMPROD.UPC_ID_XREF.UPC = :inUPC"

    Using dbConn As New OracleConnection(DataAccess.ConnectionString)
        dbConn.Open()

        Using dbCommand As New OracleCommand(sql, dbConn)
            dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            dbCommand.BindByName = True
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add("inUPC", OracleDbType.Int64).Value = upc
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add("outCursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor, DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.Output)

            Using dbAdapter As New OracleDataAdapter(dbCommand)
                dbAdapter.Fill(upcLookup)
            End Using

            dbCommand.DisposeOfAllParameters()
        End Using
    End Using

    Return upcLookup
End Function
```

When I execute the code, dbAdapter.Fill(upcLookup) throws an exception about a missing right parenthesis.

The SQL executes fine in Toad.

The outCursor references were added as an attempt to resolve the issue.  The issue occurs whether or not a cursor is used to retrieve the results.

I modified the SQL and tried to use Oracle's syntax per a KB note regarding issues with binding and ODP and ANSI syntax joins:

```
SELECT * FROM IMPROD.UPC_ID_XREF, IMPROD.UPC_ID_DESCRIPTIONS, 
IMPROD.UPC_ID_ATTRIBUTES WHERE IMPROD.UPC_ID_XREF.UPC = :inUPC
AND IMPROD.UPC_ID_XREF.UPC_ID = IMPROD.UPC_ID_DESCRIPTIONS.UPC_ID
AND IMPROD.UPC_ID_XREF.UPC_ID = IMPROD.UPC_ID_ATTRIBUTES.UPC_ID
```

This resulted in the same error (along with a cascade of other errors, including ">" being found where not expected, an extra semi colon being found, etc.  The parenthesis error was the first listed.)

I stripped the SQL down to:

```
 SELECT * FROM IMPROD.UPC_ID_XREF WHERE IMPROD.UPC_ID_XREF.UPC = :inUPC
```

but the missing parenthesis error continued.  So I went even further and used this SQL:

```
 SELECT IMPROD.UPC_ID_XREF.UPC FROM IMPROD.UPC_ID_XREF;
```

This removes the multi select (*) from the statement, the variable, and the JOINs.  Yet it still threw an error:

```
 ORA-06550: line 1, column 68:
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ">" when expecting one of the following:

 . ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
 <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
 like4 likec as between || multiset member submultiset
 The symbol "( was inserted before ">" to continue.
 ORA-06550: line 1, column 90:
 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

 . ( * % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
 <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
 like4 likec as between || multiset memb
```

Which is... a big huh?

I tried to use a constant in place of :inUPC and this did not help, so I think my binding is okay.

Speaking of binding, if I turn off BindByName I receive the error ORA-01008: not all variables bound.  I know this contradicts my statement above, but there was originally only one variable to **be** bound.

I've Google'd and read through the huge morass of posts on SO about the same error but nothing seems to fit the bill.

I can wrap SQL Server around my finger, but I am a novice in the Oracle arena.  Please help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope.  *slaps on Princess Leia buns and outfit; you'll have to imagine Peter Griffin as Leia to get the full effect*

I know this will end up being some incredibly simple fix.
Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: In your very last query, where you're selecting just one column, did you spell your column correctly? That is, is your column name really IMPROD.UPC_ID_XREF.UPC?

Comment: Yep, it holds a numeric UPC code.  (I work for a retail chain.)  I resolved the issue today by moving the code into a package and procedure (with no problems); however, I'd really like to know why ad hoc queries are so damned difficult with Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty late coming, but it bit me.

You have explicitly stated that the SQL command is a stored procedure, when it should be text.  Change:

```
dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

to:

```
dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
```

I suspect it will work like magic then.  It did for me, at any rate.

Comment: A bit late, but yes - it worked.  The simple evils of cut and paste coding come back to bite.  Thanks for the clarity!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by using a procedure rather than attempting to execute the query ad hoc.  (So the problem was not really solved, but worked around.)  I had been attempting to avoid that situation as the application had no other database dependencies associated with it.