# VBA and Oracle SQL: ORA-00907: Missing Right Parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, vba, excel

I have written some basic SQL in Oracle, which runs as expected. It selects a client, their ID and what 'services' they can provide.

However, when I add variables that are passed from VBA code the error message `ORA-00907: Missing Right Parenthesis` occurs. It is due to an `OR` in the code.

```
AND C.CURRENCY LIKE :cmbSelectAccountCcy
AND (S.SERVICEID LIKE :cmbSelectServiceType OR S.SERVICEID LIKE :cmbSelectServiceType2)
AND .... etc
```

If I remove the OR it runs as expected. The OR is part of a check that includes (at the end)

```
HAVING COUNT(S.SERVICEID) > 2
```

Allowing the 2 values to be checked, and only if the 2 (or more) are present display the client.

The combo boxes in Excel will pass the service ID as either a set value from the drop down box, or a `%` character. I assume the right parenthesis is never reached in some cases.

What is the reason that I can run the SQL query with Hard Coded values, but not passing the very same variables through VBA? I have a `Debug.Print()` statement in the VBA which is showing all the values I would expect to see passed over.

---

**UPDATE:**

Changing the name `cmbSelectServiceType2` to `cmbServiceTypeTwo` appears to have fixed the issue but, as of yet, I cannot figure out why. Any answers appreciated still! The only factor I can see is that the first is 21 chars, the second is < 20 chars. The column data type is VARCHAR2 in the table.

Tangent: The OR statement is now returning Service1 or Service1 and Service2 or Service2, i.e. a fully OR statement. The HAVING clause above was an attempt to impose that only BOTH are allowed.

---

**UPDATE 2**

Changing the '2' in cmbSelectServiceType2 to letters 'two' does not work. It seems like 20 chars is some arbitrary limit.

Comment: Sounds like a driver problem; maybe it's confused about the bind variable data type?

Comment: Thanks @alexpoole so does this mean I need to (if possible) cast the variables to their correct type, for example: `CAST(:Variable As Number)` or such? They are all of type `VARCHAR2` I'm not a dev by trade, I'm trying to get something automated in a new job, so this is me coming at it pretty blind.

Comment: You can't cast the `%` as a number. If the driver is breaking it then it's hard to guess how to work around it. Checking/updating/replacing the driver is maybe preferable but might not be possible for you? I can think of one possible approach but it's a bit hit-and-miss without knowing the underlying problem; `(S.SERVICEID = :cmbSelectServiceType OR S.SERVICEID =:cmbSelectServiceType2 OR :cmbSelectServiceType = '%' OR :cmbSelectServiceType2 = '%')`

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks again. I tried that approach just now and still 'missing right parenthesis' for any combo of variables I have passed. If I take out the 'OR' and just have the one Service ID variable it works fine, strange (to me) that it breaks with 2. Hard coding 2 with actual values works fine, as does the approach above with hard coding. If it's driver related as you say, then this is not going to be fun at all!!

Comment: "The OR is part of a check that includes (at the end) `HAVING COUNT(S.SERVICEID) > 2`" - What does that mean?

Comment: @DavidFaber that was added with help from someone else, I'm afraid. I wanted to check if the person has one, two or more of the services assigned. That should be >1 in the code, but I'm not sure how it works to be perfectly blunt. I was told if I'm passing more than one variable to group it, and to limit the search that way. A client could have service 1, service 2 and so on. The user will search for Service 1, Or service 2, or service 1 AND service 2. It doesn't matter if the person searches only for Service 1, but the client has 1 and 2. As long as the variable is there at all.

Comment: daft suggestion, but what happens if you put a space between the 2 and the ) in `S.SERVICEID LIKE :cmbSelectServiceType2)`? (I'm just wondering if the bracket is being taken to be part of the bind variable name)

Comment: @Boneist I never though of that (and vba being as awful as it is, it wouldn't suprise me), but sadly it throws the same error message about missing right parenthesis.

Comment: Hmm. And [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747684/execution-of-oracle-ad-hoc-query-with-bind-parameters-erroring-out-ora-00907-m) doesn't help?

Comment: @Boneist I'm reading it now, thanks a million. Something VERY ODD has happened (odd to me anyway). I renamed `:cmbSelectServiceType2` to `:combServiceTypeTwo`  and it seems to be working now...? That makes no sense. Could this be a length of variable issue? The first one is 21 chars (excluding the `:`)  and the second is < 20.

Comment: I would be more inclined to think it was the number causing the issue, rather than the length (well, as long as the length is <= 30), but I've never used VBA *{:-) Oracle wouldn't have a problem with the bind variable name containing a number, providing it was not at the start of the identifier, but perhaps VBA or the data provider doesn't like it?

Comment: Still sounds like a driver problem, but could be VBA... I don't understand your tangent though; do you mean you need `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT S.SERVICEID) > 2`?

Comment: @AlexPoole I was under the (wrong) impression that this `HAVING COUNT(S.SERVICE_ID) >= 2 would only return clients that have multiple service IDs, i.e. the one's the user is searching for. I now see that I'm completely miles off the mark. I'm offloading that onto the VBA as it's as handy there as anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

according to:

[Getting around the Max String size in a vba function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516702/getting-around-the-max-string-size-in-a-vba-function)

A vba function cannot handle a string with more than 255 chars, is it possible that this may be causing the problem, especially as when you cut the string length it works.

Comment: Hi, but it's the length of the variable name, once it is under 20 chars it appears to work ok. I don't know who the size of the String would factor in to be honest. The String itself is only 3 chars long.